# terraform conditional blocks with null inputs

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I have this terraform code in a resource

```
administrator_login = try(var.mode, "Default") == "Default" ? try(var.administrator_username, "testuser") : null
```

when var mode is "Default" the first part of the condition should be returning true and when administrator_username is null, it should return testuser, instead its returning null, any ideas why that could be happening?

it should return testuser when var.administrator_username is null and var.mode is "Default"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var.administrator_username` equal to `null` is still valid. It does not produce any errors, so `null` is returned. its better to use [coalesce](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/coalesce) instead of try:

```
administrator_login = coalesce(var.mode, "Default") == "Default" ? coalesce(var.administrator_username, "testuser") : null
```

Comment: thank u, if in my case var. mode is null then coalesce wouldn't be the right choice would it? @Marcin